# Proving whether a problem can be solved without the use of an algorithm.

Tags: algorithms

I wonder whether certain types of problem can be classified depending on the nature of the their solution. Some problem can be most easily solved in a logical way while other problem is most easily solved using some kind of algorithm.

But say I have a problem that I want to solve, or a theorem I want to prove. The problem seems to be of an algorithmic nature and maybe I can solve it by letting a computer running some kind of an algorithm and checking every case seperately to determine wheter the theorem is generally true or not.

But maybe there is another way of proving the theorem, which does not require the use of a computer or algorithm. But how can i know that for sure, is there a way to prove this? Is there a way to prove whether a theorem can be proved in a logical way, or if a problem can be solved without using some kind of algorithm?

Comment: Take a look to: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undecidable_problem